# I need assistance with polymorphis and interface in my project

Tags: java

```
       package zootest;




public abstract class Animal 
{


   public int numberOfLegs;
   public boolean hasWings;


   public Animal(int n, boolean w) 
   {
      numberOfLegs = n;
      hasWings = w;
   }


   public abstract void talk();


   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
       return String.format("I am an animal.");
   }
}






 package zootest;


public interface Pet 
{
    public String getOwner();
    public void transferOwner(String newOwner);
    default void sayRandomword()
    {
        System.out.println("randomness");
    }

}







 package zootest;

import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class ZooTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {




      Zoo myZoo = new Zoo();


      int dogs=0, eagles=0, birds=0;

      for(int i = 0; i < myZoo.getNumAnimals();i++)
      {
          if(myZoo.getAnimal(i) instanceof Eagle)
              eagles++;
          else if (myZoo.getAnimal(i) instanceof Bird)
              birds++;
          else if (myZoo.getAnimal(i) instanceof Dog)
              dogs++; 
      }
      System.out.println("Dogs = " + dogs +", Birds = " + birds + ", Eagles = " + eagles);


      System.out.println("\nROLL CALL!");
      for(int i = 0; i < myZoo.getNumAnimals();i++)
      {

        myZoo.getAnimal(i).talk();      
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < myZoo.getNumAnimals();i++)
      {
          if (myZoo.getAnimal(i) instanceof Dog)
          {

              myZoo.getAnimal(i).numberOfLegs = 3; 
          }
      }
      System.out.println();

      for(int i = 0; i < myZoo.getNumAnimals();i++)
      {
          if (myZoo.getAnimal(i) instanceof Eagle)
          {


              Eagle tempEagle = (Eagle)myZoo.getAnimal(i);
              tempEagle.attack();
          }
      }


      System.out.println("\nAdding another animal to show method in Zoo...");
      myZoo.addAnimal(new Bird());
      System.out.println("Total animals = " + myZoo.getNumAnimals());


      myZoo.addAnimal(new FrenchBulldog("Yohana"));

      Pet[] myPets = new Pet[myZoo.getNumAnimals()];


    }


}




    package zootest;


public class FrenchBulldog extends Dog implements Pet 
{
    private String owner;
    public FrenchBulldog(String o)
    {
        super();
        owner= o;
    }
    @Override
    public String getOwner()
    {
        return owner;
    }

    @Override
    public void transferOwner(String newOwner)
    {
        owner = newOwner;

    }
  }



    package zootest;


abstract class Horse extends Animal implements Pet 
{
    private String owner;
    public Horse (String o)
    {
            super(4,false);
            owner= o;
    }
    @Override
    public String getOwner()
    {
        return owner;
    }

    @Override
    public void transferOwner(String newOwner)
    {
        owner = newOwner;

    }
  }




 package zootest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Zoo 
{

    private ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

    public Zoo()
    {
        animals.add(new Eagle());
        animals.add(new Dog());
        animals.add(new Eagle());
        animals.add(new Bird());
        animals.add(new Eagle());
        animals.add(new Dog());
        animals.add(new Dog());
        animals.add(new Eagle());

    }

    public Animal getAnimal(int index)
    {
        return animals.get(index);
    }

    public int getNumAnimals()
    {
        return animals.size();
    }

    public void addAnimal(Animal a)
    {
        animals.add(a);
    }

}
```

Part    3:       Polymorphic    Processing  of  Pets    at  the Zoo
1. Add  at  least   one of  each    of  your    new animal  types   to  the zoo in  ZooTest.java
2. Create an    array   or  ArrayList   of  Pets
3. Loop through the zoo.        If  an  animal  is  also    a   pet,    add it  to  the pet array
4. Iterate  through the pet array   (which  should  only    have    pets)   and have    each    pet do  something   that
only    a   pet can do

ok so basically the code above is my assignment, so far i have already created an interface and two pets which are FrenchBulldog and a horse which basically means half of my assignment is already done but I need help on part 3 which i wrote above

Comment: let me know if you need to see my zoo class aswell so i can post it because i forgot to do it in my question

Comment: You should make your code runnable

Comment: hold on let me post the rest of my code

Comment: ok i think it should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through the instructions.

> 1. Add at least one of each of your new animal types to the zoo in ZooTest.java

This would require **implementing** your interface in a subclass of `Animal` and adding an instance of it to the zoo list. e.g.

```
List<? extends Animal> zoo = new ArrayList<>();
zoo.add(new Fox());
zoo.add(new Dog());
zoo.add(new Bear());
// plus more?
```

> 2. Create an array or ArrayList of Pets

Simple enough. Create a list with `Pet` as the type. A list makes more sense for this situation.

```
List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
```

> 3. Loop through the zoo. If an animal is also a pet, add it to the pet array

In order to determine if an object is of a certain type, we can use the `instanceof` keyword. After that check, we can safely cast to the desired type.

```
if (animal instanceof Pet)
    pets.add((Peg) animal);
```

> 4. Iterate through the pet array (which should only have pets) and have each pet do something that

Seems fairly obvious. Iterate the pets list.

```
for (Pet pet : pets) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: public void addAnimal(Animal a)
    {
        animals.add(a);
    }

Comment: i wrote a method that would add the animals i put using it

Comment: can u show me an example of the Pet array u have like including the animals and all that

Comment: Those are just example animals. It's up to you to implement them. For pets, also implement Pet like you have done for Dog.

Comment: I tried doing that but since Horse is an abstract its not letting me so can u tell me how i can do it

Comment: Either make it not abstract or extend it.

Comment: by extending it do u mean implement its methods?